# Грамматические свойства и грамматические признаки части речи

Tags: терминология

Вопрос очень простой по формулировке.

***Грамматические свойства и грамматические признаки (частей речи).
Что это такое по сути своей*** (сами понятия, списки и примеры - не обязательно) ***и в чем разница?***

*Для меня **признак** и **свойство** - вещи достаточно разные. В грамматике - тоже. Но при обсуждении одного вопроса возникло подозрение, что эти вещи смешиваются. В результате возникло непонимание.*

Comment: Думаю, термин "грамматические свойства слова (части речи)" не является общепринятым. Примеры употребления: (1)Грамматические свойства кратких прилагательных: http://www.textologia.ru/russkiy/morfologia/imya-prilagatelnoe/grammaticheskie-svoystva-kratkih-prilagatelnih/1264/?q=463&n=1264 (2) Грамматические свойства слова это...: http://lingv_ossetian.academic.ru/85/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0

Answer (score 2):

Свойство – необходимое условие, признак – достаточное. Например, ядовитость – свойство синильной кислоты (а не признак). Число оканчивается на 5 – признак делимости его на 5 (но не свойство).

В грамматике вряд ли стоит различать такие вещи. Вроде бы они и не различаются.

Comment: *Свойство – необходимое условие, признак – достаточное.* -  Чтобы говорить о необходимых и достаточных условиях, надо прежде сформулировать причинно-следсвенную связь.  "Признак чего?" и "свойство чего?".

Comment: "Сформулировать причинно-следсвенную связь" — хорошо сказано, г-н @Morkovkin. Грамотно. )

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58181/discussion-between-morkovkin-and-niemand).

Answer (score 2):

Есть широкие и узкие значения терминов. В широком значении это синонимы:

Свойство – признак, отличительная особенность.

Признак – показатель, категория, по которой можно узнать словоформу.

В узком смысле грамм.признак - это грамматическое значение, в сущности определённый набор грамматических категорий (морфологических) и синтаксических функций для каждой части речи.

Т. е. для существительного грамматическим **признаком** будет **значение    предметности**. А вот уже средством выражения предметности являются грам. категории, которых у существительного 4: одушевлённость/неодушевлённость, род, число, падеж. Это перечислены морфологические признаки. Также существуют словообразовательные: суффиксы-тель, -щик, -ник, -ниj, -ость, -ств (о).

Главный **признак глагола - изменение по временам.** неважно, что глагол называет.

Грамматические **свойства слова** - это **возможность проявления признаков**, т.е. совокупность признаков:

1) значение слова как части речи (категориальное значение);

2) словообразовательная структура;

3) способность к формальному изменению;

4) грамм. категории (число, падеж – у имени; вид, залог, время, наклонение, лицо – у глагола);

5) синтаксическая функция.

Если короче, то: грамматические свойства слова — это 1) его частеречная принадлежность, 2) способность определенным образом изменяться (иметь совокупность словоформ) или быть неизменяемым и 3) его грамматические значения.

Одними и теми же свойствами могут обладать различные части речи (неизменяемостью, например, и синтаксической функцией обстоятельства похожи наречие и деепричастие, отсутствием синтаксической функции все служебные части речи).

Признак - это обязательное свойство, присущее определённой части речи. Например, существительное обозначает предмет, глагол - действие предмета,наречие - признак предмета , признак действия, признак признака, а местоимение  указывает, но не называет предмет, качество, количество.

Comment: Спасибо!!! Вот это уже лучше (в сравнении с первым ответом). И в общем-то близко к тому, что я сам представлял. Беда только в том, что далеко не во всех источниках прослеживается последовательное разделение понятий. Вот, к примеру, у наречия в соответствии в этим подходом естественно выделяется единственное ***свойство*** - неизменяемость (если надо найду ссылки). А по другой "школе" его перечисляют среди признаков, что очевидно идет в разрез с данной трактовкой. Вот тут как-то надо бы разобраться...

Comment: *Грамматические свойства слова - это возможность проявления признаков,* - вот это мне, кстати, не нравится. Ну как "свойство" может быть "возможностью"?! Это вещи совершенно разных понятийных полей. Хотя смысл я понимаю, но надо бы как-то аккуратнее сформулировать...

Answer (score 1):

**Из словаря:**

СВОЙСТВО, Существенный признак, отличающий один предмет, одно явление от другого;  ПРИЗНАК, **Показатель, примета, знак, по которым можно узнать,** **определить что-л.**

А теперь попробуем на практическом примере отличить грамматический признак от  грамматического свойства.

К примеру, возьмем грамматическую **категорию падежа.** Изменение по падежам является признаком имен? Да, является, по этому у признаку мы устанавливаем принадлежность части речи к именам. Также мы можем сказать, что имена **обладают свойством** изменяться по падежам. Существительное тоже обладает свойством изменяться по падежам, но склонение не является признаком существительного (склоняться могут и другие имена)

**А тогда как можно определить, что перед нами именно существительное?**  Здесь уже нужен набор признаков или обобщенный грамматический признак, который условно называют предметностью(одушевлённость/неодушевлённость, род, число, падеж). Вот предметность —  признак именно существительного, но это одновременно и свойство существительного.

Итак, термины могут совпадать по значению,  могут различаться. **Склонение для  существительного является свойством, но не является признаком,  а предметность является и свойством, и признаком.**

Comment: *Итак, термины могут совпадать по значению, могут различаться.* - Если можно, применительно к грамматике, термины различаются или совпадают.

Comment: Весь ответ на эту тему. Склонение для существительного является грамматическим свойством сущ., но не является грамматическим признаком сущ. (термины различаются) , а предметность является и грамматическим свойством, и грамматическим  признаком сущ. (термины совпадают)